# ionic 5 with slider does not honor allowTouchMove

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, swiper.js

i am using ionic 5 with swiper js and using the docummentation i have container looking like below:

```
<swiper-container #swiper (afterinit)="swiperReady()" [pagination]="false" [allowTouchMove]="false">
```

i want to disable swiping from one slide to another by touch or swipe gesture. however, adding the above property does not have any effect. i can still swipe.

the pagination property as a test works just fine.

reference: https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-allowTouchMove